# SwiftUI ScrollView animated scrolling is sometimes slow

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got a simple chat view that scrolls up to reveal new messages that appear at the bottom of the chat. What's weird is that sometimes, the duration of the scroll animation is much longer than normal.

[image: Animated GIF showing sometimes-slow scrolling behavior.]

I think it happens when a message comes in while the animation is still underway.

My code looks like this:

```
struct
OverlayChatView: View
{
    @ObservedObject public  var     stream          :   ChatStream
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
                    ForEach(self.stream.messages) { inMsg in
                        ChatMessageCell(message: inMsg)
                    }
                    .onChange(of: self.stream.messages, perform: { inMessages in
                        if inMessages.count < 1 { return }
                    
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)) {
                            scrollView.scrollTo(inMessages.last!.id, anchor: .bottom)
                        }
                    })
                    .padding(8)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`self.stream` is passed in from an `@ObservedObject` `ChatStream` with a simple Timer inserting a new message every 5.0 seconds. If the interval is 2.0 seconds, then it just continually scrolls upward slowly.

One other thing I notice is that `.onChange()` gets called three times for each insert. Perhaps my `ChatStream` is doing something dumb. I mention it because just invoking the animation three times in quick succession doesn't cause the slowdown. It seems more related to where the scroll is currently vs where it has to go.

Any idea how I can avoid this slowdown?

Comment: I've had this happen to me before too, also in a scroll view. Would be interested in a solution as well.

Comment: I'm having this exact same behavior now.  Did you find any solution?

Comment: No solution yet.

Comment: @alionthego I'm thinking I'm going to have to take the elaborate step of making a custom animation so that I can detect the end of the scroll animation, and then use that to coalesce the scroll events that might come in. Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this bug when testing my app for iOS 14 (the issue seems to have been fixed in iOS 15).

The solution I found is to just wrap the withAnimation call within a main thread async call, like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)) {
        scrollView.scrollTo(inMessages.last!.id, anchor: .bottom)
    }
}
```

Comment: Intersting. Well, that employer can crash and burn for all I care. But I’ll try to remember next time I have to do this.